# What is the best way to rename okd cluster's master?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

We are running a cluster "*Single master and multiple nodes*" (in https://docs.okd.io/latest/install/index.html#multi-masters-using-native-ha-colocated). Let's call our servers oomaster1, oonode1 and oonode2.

I would like to add other masters one day and I think the first step would be to add a VIP oomaster, now pointing only to oomaster1, and then rename the cluster (currently oomaster1) to oomaster.

What would be the best way to proceed ? I mean I can just stop all okd related services and replace oomaster1 (and its address) with oomaster (and its address) in every file in /etc/origin and /etc/etcd and then restart services. But I suppose it is more complex...

Thanks in advance for advices

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace the existing `cluster`(`master` and `nodes`) with new `cluster` which is configured as new `hostname`, because the `master` and `nodes` are deployed the various `certificates` based on `master` `hostname` for encrypted communication and authentication. And I have no idea whether or not the existing `master` hostname can change.